# Automate Jira state transitions when PR are merged into different branches

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, bitbucket-cloud

We're using Jira and Bitbucket-cloud, and our workflow involves merging changes into the staging environment first and only after that - to prod. We'd like to automate the respective ticket transitions between the states. For example:

- code review -> available on staging - when the code is merged into staging
- available on staging -> available on prod - when the code is merged into master

However, we found that the bitbucket triggers lack granularity: when the same code is merged into the master branch, the same trigger fires again causing the same transition.

What are the common practices to automate such transitions?